# Find data on run time of Rstudio Version 0.99.903 in OSX 10.11.5

Tags: r, macos, rstudio

I opened R with RStudio for the first time in may of 2015 when I started my research project. I didn't know the first thing about R at the time. Over the last year and a half I have taught myself the R language and become reasonably competent in its use. I thought it would be an interesting data visualization to plot the number of hours Rstudio has been active on my computer over time and analyse this as a time series to give an estimate of the effort it takes to learn the language. Is there anyway to extract this data, from OSX, Rstudio or R itself?

Comment: this could then be referenced for those delightful situations were clinical or lab scientists ask "Why is your research taking so long, aren't you just putting the data into the computer and getting results?"

Comment: My guess is, only if you were logging it. This post describes software to log your computer use: https://jojomio.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/get-more-productive/